# Laravel - Working with sessions between controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to show some values in all app, and sometimes I need to use these values between controllers.
I was trying to use Session, but I maybe it is not the answer to that, because if I am not wrong, Laravel store the session data temporarily in memory and only after everything has been executed, will it dump the session data into storage (file, cookie, redis, whatever).

So for example, I have a controller like that:

```
class GiftController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard(){
        $token = (Session::has('token')) ? Session::get('token') : NULL;
        if (is_null($token)){
           return view('test.erro', ['message' => 'no session!']);
        }else{
           return view('test.ok', ['message' => $token]);
        } 
    }


    public function setsession(){
          Session::put('token','xxxxxxxxxxxx');
          return redirect('test/dashboard');  
    }
}
```

In this case,  if I do an echo on Session::get('token') into the setsession(), is showing the value,  but when it goes to the dashboard(), the session shows nothing.

What I am doing wrong?
or What is the better Idea to use instead off session?

I am using the Laravel Framework 5.8.37

Comment: Check which method you using to store the session. As you say Laravel uses Redis, File, Database, etc... If you using Database, you need create the Database Schema. If you have it as Redis, you want to have Redis up and running, etc...

Comment: Check this in `config/session.php`

Comment: Also remember in Laravel 5.8 you have the `session('key')` helper to access the session.

Comment: in config/session.php  is  'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')

Comment: Check you have the `storage/framework/sessions` folder there. There's where the file driver stores the session info.

Comment: Check your `.env` file too. Might be defining a different `SESSION_DRIVER` value. Maybe there you have redis or database.

Comment: I was using an app.yaml, since I am using the GCP app engine.  But the answer was  very close what ware you thinking. The session was in this file was SESSION_DRIVER: cookie.    you are the man!  Tks!

Comment: So I change :  config/session.php is 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but I got it with the [markskayff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3443551/markskayff) help.

He told me to Check my .env file, and he was right! It was a different SESSION_DRIVER value from config/session.php

In config/session.php was 'driver' => env ('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')

Despite not having .env file but app.yaml since I am doing this project in GCP app engine, the session in this file was SESSION_DRIVER: cookie.

So I changed in config / session.php  the line 'driver' => env ('SESSION_DRIVER', '**file**') to 'driver' => env ('SESSION_DRIVER', '**cookie**').

And now it is working!

Comment: Well, in the `env ('SESSION_DRIVER', <second-param>)` , the second param is just the default value used in case the an .env definition is not found. You had it as `file` as default, but cookie defined in your app.yml. So, I'm still a bit confused why it wasn't working with the cookie driver from the beginning. IF you changed your defaults to "cookie" using ` env ('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie')` that should have changed nothing at all ... that means two things to me: 1) the current env config is not being picked up 2) the file driver has an issue.

Comment: Weird, because when changed to  'driver' => env ('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie') and the app.yaml  to  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie start to work.     In my case I am not using the .env, but  app.yaml